# Checking whether realm in the authentication dialog contains a string

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to check if the realm of the website from the Firefox authentication dialog contains the specified string:

```
document.getElementById("prompt-password-message").textContent.indexOf("STRING")
```

where STRING is the string I am looking for.

Any ideas why the above code doesn't work?

Comment: if you `console.log(document.getElementById("prompt-password-message").textContent);` what do you get?

Comment: are you sure `document.getElementById("prompt-password-message")` is returning anything? iirc there are non standard ways to go about DOM manipulation in add-ons/extensions

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the 'content document' or else the getElementById() will return nothing...

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Accessing_content_documents

```
content.document.getElementById("prompt-password-message").textContent.indexOf("STRING")
```

Comment: No idea why it "worked" for the OP but he was actually referring to an [element of a XUL document](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/f4a40f677391/mobile/xul/chrome/content/prompt/promptPassword.xul#l35), not something inside the content document. Which just means that the question is missing a lot more information than immediately obvious.

Comment: Ahh, ok well it was a stab in the dark. Not much to work from.